# In VB 2008, how can one subprocedure accept different arrays of a structure in different calls?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2008, structure

I'm writing a character creator for my friend's tabletop RPG using Visual Basic 2008 as a learning exercise so please be kind if I've made stupid choices. :]

I have three arrays of a structure, one called m_OwnedWeapons that's created from a structure called Weapons, one called m_OwnedArmor created from a structure called Armor, and one called m_OwnedPotions created from a structure called Potions.  They have some similarities and several differences but a lot of the time I need to do an identical operation on each of them.  For example, when the index in a listbox changes, my program searches through each of these arrays of a structure to find which holds the item and then it updates the displayed values (cost, description, etc).

My problem is that I'd like a way that I only have to write the search code one time.  Right now I have to write it three times because it has to search each by name.  I have this same code posted three times, only once it refers to m_OwnedPotions, once it refers to m_OwnedArmor, and once it refers to m_Owned Weapons:

```
LoopCountInteger = 0  
    If m_OwnedPotionsCounterInteger > 0 Then  
        Do Until LoopCountInteger >= m_OwnedPotionsCounterInteger Or ItemFoundBoolean = True  
            If InventoryListBox.SelectedItem.Equals(m_OwnedPotions(LoopCountInteger).NameString) Then  
                ItemFoundBoolean = True  
            End If  
            LoopCountInteger += 1  
        Loop  
    End If
```

Is there a way to maybe write some kind of subprocedure with this code that accepts the array of a structure name as its parameter?  Is this not possible because one is an array of a structure of Weapons, one of Armor, and one of Items?

Maybe I just need one array of a structure called Items that will hold the fields required by all item types, but if I do it that way it seemed untidy because that one structure had so many fields unused for most items.  I don't know.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: unless you have some special need to learn vs2008 specifically, I recommend to go get vs2013, the express edition is free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So solving this type of problem is normally done through inheritance. You have three different types of objects that share some basic properties but are also different things. To represent these objects in your code, create a base class that will hold their common properties (name, cost, description, etc.) and a subclass for each of the more concrete types.

Here is one sort of exammple:

```
Public Class Equipment
    Public Name As String
    Public Desc As String
    Public Cost As Integer
    Public Weight As Integer
End Class

Public Class Weapon
    Inherits Equipment
    Public MinimumDamage As Integer
    Public MaximumDamage As Integer
    Public Speed As Integer
End Class

Public Class Potion
    Inherits Equipment
    Public Effect As String
End Class

Public Class Armor
    Inherits Equipment
    Public SpeedPenalty As Integer
    Public ArmorClass As Integer
End Class
```

Now, using [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) you can write procedures that can operate on any of these items by accepting a parameter of the base type.  Your program can also have a container that holds all of the equipment so you only have to search one list to find the object that is selected.

Comment: That sounds perfect!  Thank you.  And to think, I have previously wondered what the point of inheritance was.  Concrete example: check. :D